# Compiling MFC on Visual Studio 6.0

Tags: mfc, visual-c++-6

I'm painfully debugging a legacy VS 6.0 MFC app, and I'd really like to step into MFC code. Now, the code did ship with VS6, and the symbols (mfc42.pdb) too, but the debugger asserts

> 'Symbols loaded (source information stripped)'

upon attaching. By [these](http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2007/04/symbols-for-mfc-source-code.html) tips, all copies of mfc42.pdb on my machine are indeed stripped (their size is 1.5M-2M, nowhere near 10M). I get meaningful stacks, but am not able to step in MFC code.

I'm currently trying to re-compile MFC to obtain codeview symbols (yes, the situation is *that* desparate). I tried following [this](http://www.usenet.com/newsgroups/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.tools.mfc/msg00157.html) nice walkthrough by Daniel Howard, but I keep bumping into the following linker errors:

> ...
>   delayimp.lib 
>      Creating library ..\lib\mfc42.LIB and object ..\lib\mfc42.exp
>   mfc42.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall CTime::operator==(class CTime)const " (??8CTime@@QBEHV0@@Z)
>   mfc42.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall CTime::operator!=(class CTime)const " (??9CTime@@QBEHV0@@Z)
>   mfc42.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall CTime::operator<(class CTime)const " (??MCTime@@QBEHV0@@Z)
>   mfc42.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall CTime::operator>(class CTime)const " (??OCTime@@QBEHV0@@Z)
>   mfc42.DLL : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals

CTime was implemented in TIMECORE.cpp, which indeed doesn't implement such operators.  I couldn't locate the operator users.

Anyone has any insight into this?
Any indirect advice would be great too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is defined in AFX.INL in VC98\MFC\Include\AFX.INL.
You've probably added only the .cpp to your project.

Stepping into MFC code is a must have. MFC code is a must see. It makes you humble and angry at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

My memory is usually pretty bad and this was a long time ago, but I seem to remember that a version of the libraries compiled and linked for debugging was one of the additional options of the VC6++ installer.

Comment: Thanks Manni. VC6++ indeed comes with MFC42d.dll and the likes, if that is what you mean - but i need full symbols (codeview) for the production version, MFC42.dll. Do you remember installing *that*?
I checked again per your reply - there was this MFC installation component called 'Source Browser'. Adding it didn't seem to make a difference, and googling around indicates its probably some sort of an object browser / intellisense predecessor.